# React component not updating values after element is deleted of specific index

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to create a shopping list with delete button, but when I click on it, other item is deleted and previous value remains there on screen, even when deleted second time. Please assume the custom buttons and icons are already separate packages Here's the code -

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { CButton, CDeleteButton } from '@custom/pkg';

const ShoppingList = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState(
        [{ name: 'Apple', price: 60 }, { name: 'Banana', price: 20 }]
    )

    return (
        <>
            <h2>Product List</h2>
            {state.map(({name, price}, idx) => (
                <>
                    <div key={idx}>
                        <div>{name}</div>
                        <div>{price}</div>
                        <div>
                            <CButton id={idx} onClick={() => {
                                setState((prev) => [...prev.splice(idx, 1)])
                            }}>
                                <CDeleteButton/>
                            </CButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}

export default ShoppingList;
```

This component is imported in a modal component and rendered. If I delete `"Apple"`, it shows on screen still and `"Banana"` is removed, and vice versa.

Comment: Do not use the array indices as keys. If you do not have unique identifiers for each item, better use ```<div key={`${name}-${idx}`}>``` which will make it harder to clash with previous id when an element is removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that you are using a React key that isn't associated to the mapped elements. When you insert or delete elements the proceeding elements all shift position and their key changes, but from React's perspective the key in that position is the same so React bails on rerendering. In other words, when you delete an element in the middle, the element shifted up takes the previously existing key and isn't rerendered.

This is why using the array index is a poor choice when mapping arrays if you are mutating the underlying data.

Either add a GUID or some other unique property to each element to be used as a key, or use a combination of properties to generate one. The React key also needs to be on the outermost mapped element, the `Fragment` in your case. Since the fragment isn't necessary in the map callback, you're only returning a single node, it can be removed.

Using `.splice` also isn't suggested since it mutates an array in-place. If you want to remove an element from an array you should use `.slice` or `.filter`.

## Solution 1

Using an added `id` property.

```
const ShoppingList = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([
    { id: 0, name: 'Apple', price: 60 }, // add id property
    { id: 1, name: 'Banana', price: 20 },
  ]);

  const removeItem = id => () => {
    setState(prev => prev.filter((el) => el.id !== id)); // filter by id
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Product List</h2>
      {state.map(({ id, name, price }) => (
        <div key={id}> // id as key
          <div>{name}</div>
          <div>{price}</div>
          <div>
            <CButton id={id} onClick={removeItem(id)}> // pass id to handler
              <CDeleteButton/>
            </CButton>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

## Solution 2

Using index and computed React key from properties.

```
const ShoppingList = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([
    { name: 'Apple', price: 60 },
    { name: 'Banana', price: 20 },
  ]);

  const removeItem = index => () => {
    setState(prev => prev.filter((el, i) => i !== index)); // filter by index
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Product List</h2>
      {state.map(({ name, price }, idx) => (
        <div key={`${name}-${price}`}> // computed key
          <div>{name}</div>
          <div>{price}</div>
          <div>
            <CButton id={idx} onClick={removeItem(idx)}> // pass index to handler
              <CDeleteButton/>
            </CButton>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Using a unique id as the index instead of a `.map` index worked beautifully for me. You gave the answer in the first sentence -- kudos.

Answer (score 1):

You should spread the prev array and then use `splice`.

```
<CButton id={idx} onClick={()=>{setState((prev)=>[...prev].splice(idx,1))}}>
```