# id in useRef changed when try delete element from array of items - React

Tags: reactjs, tsx, react-tsx

I have list of Question I am trying to delete question when click on remove to access the parent I was used a useRef but when click on remove he remove just last item for question list, and if click on any `remove` will delete last element, if I have three element in the list and try to remove first element the id for first element change to id for the next element and last item deleted and item want to remove still existing but her id change

add function

```
    const [ids, setIds] = useState<any>(1);
    const [mcqAnswerList, setMcqAnswerList] = useState<any[]>([]);

    const handleCreateMcqQuestion = () => {
        setMcqAnswerList(
            mcqAnswerList.concat({
                question: <McqQuestion />,
                id: ids,
            })
        );
    };
```

delete function

```
const handleDeleteMcqQuestion = (id: any) => {
  const printNewList = mcqAnswerList.filter((x: any, i: any) => x.id != id);
  setMcqAnswerList(printNewList);
}
```

delete button

```
<div
    className="mx-[7px] w-[80px] cursor-pointer"
    onClick={_ => {handleDeleteMcqQuestion(mcqRef.current.getAttribute("data-id"));
    }}>
    <label id="remove">
        <Remove />
    </label>
</div>
```

section want delete it

```
<HStack spacing="24px" py={"9px"} data-id={good} ref={mcqRef}>
  <FormControl id="type">
  </FormControl>
</HStack>
```

just video 34sec to explain the problem [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16sj35iB9mPuiOEyw3AN7XewcZZVpCFt7?usp=sharing)

when try to remove second element
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

any one want to know the reason and solution for this problem chick this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68876007/11718792